# Is there any way to simplify this method that takes the first letter from first, middle, and last names and joins them together?

Tags: python-3.7

```
def to_initials(name):

    initials = [x[0] for x in name.split()]
    return ''.join(initials)


print(to_initials("Kelvin Bridges"))        # => "KB"
print(to_initials("Michaela Yamamoto"))     # => "MY"
print(to_initials("Mary La Grange"))        # => "MLG"
```

I'm trying to create a method that takes the first letter from each name and prints the initials. Is there a simpler way to write this?

Comment: A 2-line function is pretty simple already...  You *could* put the list comprehension directly in the `.join()` call, thus avoiding the `initials` variable, but there's no actual advantage to doing things that way.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do more than leave out the intermediate variable and using a generator expression instead of the list comprehension (i.e. leaving out the square brackets). Other than that, it seems like a perfectly fine simple function!

```
def to_initials(name):
    return ''.join(x[0] for x in name.split())
```